# Keras vis: how to deal with multiple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Is there any way to visualize neural network attention in [Keras-vis](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis) for a neural network involving multiple inputs?

In the simplest scenario, there are two inputs, `input_a` and `input_b`. Apply a `Dense` layer on each input, merge the results and map them using another `Dense` layer to one of the classes. The attention could be visualized across all inputs.

Comment: Hello, have you solved your problem? I'm facing something similar. Thanks

Comment: Hello, do you have a solution to this?

Comment: @ssm unfortunately nothing generic which I can offer

Comment: Were you able to get this to work with Keras-Vis, I am trying to modify it, but I could use some help if you have already tried that.